# Imports not working even with __init__.py file

Tags: python, python-import

I keep getting the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'

I have the following structure:

```
basefolder
  |- main.py
  |- helpers
        |- __init__.py
        |- connection.py
        |- datasource.py
```

my main.py has the following code:

```
from helpers import *
```

I've tried leaving the `__init__.py` file blank. I've also tried adding the following code to the `__init__.py`

```
from helpers.connection import get_conn
from helpers.datasource import get_data
```

Nothing works, I'm losing my mind. :)

Comment: I assume `helpers` is `helpers.py` and you just misspelled it in the structure, right?

Comment: try ```from .connection import get_conn``` inside the ```__init__.py```

Comment: @Vadim `helpers` is a folder and spelled correctly I guess.

Comment: You need another `__init__.py` inside `basefolder` to tell Python to import from the current directory.

Comment: @Vadim helpers is a folder.

Comment: I'm just blind. Thanks

Comment: @AjayDabas i added another empty __init__.py file inside base folder. Still can't find module.

Comment: @AccLok if it can't even find the helpers module, does it make sense to update the __init__.py file that resides in the helpers folder?

Comment: Not `init.py`, I said `__init__.py` :)

Comment: for some reason when i write _ _ <-- it just bolds... i did put the name as _ _ init _ _.py (no space between _)

Comment: @mikelowry because stackoverflow supports markdown in comments, try adding \` around the filename: `__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

You can try relative import in `main.py`

```
from .helpers import *
```

Comment: Tried this, getting the following:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.helpers'; '__main__' is not a package`